# Select/deselect all node with same ID on fancytree plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I am trying to create company structure. 
One employee can been employeed in two sector, but this is same employee with same ID `id = employee1`.

Checking if is item selected or deselected and this is working.

I having problem with nodes with same id.

When selected node with id employee1, I want select/deselect all node where is id employee1.

Thank you in advance.

```
<div id="companyEmplyee">
    <ul>
        <li class="folder" id="company1">Company
            <ul>
                <li class="folder" id="sector1">Sector 1
                    <ul>
                        <li class="emplyee1">Emplyee 1</li>  
                        <li id="emplyee2">Emplyee 2</li>        
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="folder" id="sector2">Sector 2
                    <ul>
                        <li class="emplyee1">Emplyee 1</li>  
                        <li id="emplyee35">Emplyee 35</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>                                                   
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var tree = $("#companyEmplyee").fancytree({
            checkbox: true,
            selectMode: 2,
            keyPathSeparator: "/",

            clones: {
                highlightClones: true
            },
            select: function (event, data) {
                var s = data.tree.getNodeByKey(data.node.key);
                var s3 = s.key;
                var s2 = $.map(data.tree.getSelectedNodes(), function (node) {//                                                                        
                    return node.key;
                });

                if ($.inArray(s3, s2) == -1) {//                                                                      
                    $("tr#" + s3).addClass("deleted");
                    //DESELECTED
                    $('table#tblID tr#' + s.key).remove();
                    alert(s.key + ' DESELECT');

                }

                else {
                    //SELECTED
                    alert(s.key + ' SELECT');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't repeat ids. They must be unique. https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` should be unique in same document, use general class `emplyee1` instead :

```
<div id="companyEmplyee">
    <ul>
        <li class="folder" id="company1">Company
            <ul>
                <li class="folder" id="sector1">Sector 1
                    <ul>
                        <li class="emplyee1">Emplyee 1</li>  
                        <li id="emplyee2">Emplyee 2</li>        
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="folder" id="sector2">Sector 2
                    <ul>
                        <li class="emplyee1">Emplyee 1</li>  
                        <li id="emplyee35">Emplyee 35</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>                                                   
</div>
```

Or use unique ids, like you see in **[fancytree documentation](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html)** the key (Node id) should be unique :

> Node id (must be unique inside the tree)
>
> ---

**Update :**

Try to use the following hack :

```
select: function (event, data) {
    if(data.node.extraClasses!=''){
      if( $(data.node.li).find('.fancytree-node').hasClass('fancytree-selected') )
            $('.'+data.node.extraClasses).addClass('fancytree-selected');
      else
            $('.'+data.node.extraClasses).removeClass('fancytree-selected');
  }
}
```

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/KcxRd/509/)**.

hope this helps.

Comment: This is OK and I change it. I still have a problem how select/deselect all node with same class (value).

Comment: That's it . Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Duplicated Id are invalid in HTML, violates the spec and cause problems.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Assign classes instead of ids.

Comment: This is OK and I change it. I still have a problem how select/deselect all node with same class (value).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the previous answers, duplicate node keys are not allowed in Fancytree (and duplicate IDs are not allowed in HTML as well).

Since it is a common scenario to have multiple object instances inside one tree, there is a concept of 'clones'.

Basically you include the `clones` extension and pass the employee ID as `refKey` instead of `key`, e.g.

```
<li data-refKey="emplyee1">Emplyee 1</li>
```

You also need to enable the extension:

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
    extensions: ["clones"],
    checkbox: true,
    selectMode: 2,
    ...
```

After that, you can access related instances like so:

```
select: function(event, data) {
    var nodes = data.node.getCloneList();
    ...
},
```

See here for details: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/ExtClones
and example http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-ext-clones.html